# GUI internals, looking for turorials

Tags: qt, widget, toolkit

There are tons of resources on how to program using the APIs of various widget toolkits but I can't seem to find much in the way of a tutorial on how to create widget toolkits themselves or how they work n detail. They are basically just black boxes to me right now.

There is some info on QT:
http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:QtInternals

but it seems quite specific to QT and not geared towards general theory.

Could anyone point me to some resources?

Thanks for reading

Comment: They're really *intended* to be black boxes to the programmers. You don't need to know how widgets work internally just to be able to use them in your application. Not only is that much easier and convenient for the programmer, it also keeps them from relying on implementation details that the OS may change from version to version.

Answer (score 2):

There are powerpoint presentaion slides on the following link:

http://aplcenmp.apl.jhu.edu/~davids/605741/handouts/6_SWT_Programming.pdf

Also you may have a look on pdf given on the following link:

http://www.loria.fr/~dutech/DDZ/SWT.pdf

Comment: Thanks This is helpful but I was hoping for something a little lower level and more in depth. Do you happen to know of any books on this topic and/or possibly ones that are agnostic to a widget toolkit?

Answer (score 2):

It would have been great to know which programming language you are using (or you'll use) to develop widgets.

Anyways,there is a link which shows the basic concepts behind widgets and also their creation:

http://star.pst.qub.ac.uk/idl/Widget_Programming_Concepts.html

Go through the tutorial/description to see if it meets your need.

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Actually I am using Ada. Thanks for the link and thanks again for all your time.